# PGAdmin: Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

i got this problem with postgreSQL, when i do a simple query of anything (CRUD), sometimes it works and almost always shows this message:

> Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.

I don't know how to solve it and it started to irritate me, anyone know how to fix it?

**UPDATE 1**

I have been searching and it seems the pgadmin4 the problem (it seems because it's not 100% developed yet), i have been using pgadmin3 and that error doesn't show up.

Answer (score 4):

solution is:

select the database where you lost the connection.

then on the right hand side select SQL

For example in the picture  (shopdb) is the db where I lost the connection to.

[image]
 After that PgAdmin will ask you if you would like to reconnect to this database...
[image]
 click ok

you will notice a message retreiving data from the server

Answer (score 3):

The reason this happened for me was a syntax error in the query. Check your syntax and try again, maybe this suffices

Comment: It's not always a syntax error, the problem seems to be pgadmin4 because it's not 100% developed. I have been using pgadmin3 without a problem.

Comment: Same reason for me. Syntax error gives this message. I was even testing if my server is up ;)

Comment: It seems to only be certain syntax errors "select from users" gives this problem, but "select not_a_column_on_the_users_table from users;" doesn't

Comment: @JohnNaegle I wouldn't call your second example a syntax error. The syntax is valid, it is just semantically nonsense

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed.

Upgrade to pgAdmin4 version 2.0. https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: i faced this problem in pgAdmin4 version 2

Comment: You need wait for version 2.1: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2602

Comment: version 2.1 is released, but they changed target version, so we need wait for version 2.2...

Comment: still a problem for me in 4 2.1

Answer (score 2):

Change the versión of pgAdmin, use pgAdmin 3, its a problem frequently between Windows 10 and pgAdmin4.

Answer (score 2):

I have similiar problem before, im using postgre 9.6.1-1 
I can do select without condition (ex: `select * from foodtable`) and i can do insert too.. But if i do select or edit or delete using a condition (ex: `select * from foodtable where taste='sweet'`) the output is like your

> Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.

I try reinstall (After uninstall delete all leftover data) and delete C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin (delete all data inside pgAdmin Folder)
And its works

Update-> Your table name and field name must lowercase

Comment: It seems that has so many bugs pgAdmin 4. I was investigating and there are so other problems with encoding, my recomendation is to use pgAdmin 3, doesn't show those problems. I guess we must wait until they solve and the new interface i don't like it too much hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Juuuuust in case someone googled this post like i did.
If you have **JSON** column AND you want to see ANY result in pgAdmin, cast JSON into VARCHAR like

```
SELECT id, metadata::VARCHAR FROM data_table;
```

It doesn't matter if content is NULL or not, **JSON** doesn't work. Maybe there are other types or values that can't be parsed by pgAdmin as well.

Note: you can still insert values and recieve them after cast, so the problem is on JS side *(put one more coin into your "Hate JS" jar)*.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run & provide output of these sql queries from pgAdmin4?

```
1) SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
2) SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;
```

And what is the encoding set for your current database connection on which you are trying to run query (Right click on your database, click on Properties > Definition Tab > Check Encoding, Collation & Character type) ?

I'm suspecting you are facing issues due to encoding.

Comment: `My encoding is: UTF8`
`My Collation is: Spanish_Ecuador.1252`
`My Character type is: Spanish_Ecuador.1252`

Comment: Okay as I suspected, This is known issue with encoding and already reported https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/1983.

Answer (score 1):

just change the column name and run the query , it worked for me.

my column name was **timestamp**, it conflicted with **datatype** so i changed **timestamp** by **_timestamp**

Comment: I created a column "description" I think this is the reason for me too. But I don't want to change the column name.

Answer (score 1):

We have just experienced this on a standalone windows machine.

After reinstalling things and looking everywhere (logs, running psql in shell - all was good)  then we found out that it was an older firefox that was the culprit.

So - please ensure that your browser is up to date :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I pressed F7 or Explain in drop-down list near the Execute button. Then I saw where exactly the trouble was. pgAdmin4 didn`t like the name of my column. Then I went to problem column and renamed it.

Comment: Probably, but pgAdmin3 doesn't have this problems, runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem
but i can create DB and table successful 
and my version is:
window10 pro x64 
9.5 (X86)

### pgAdmin4

after i change to 9.4 (X86)+ pgAdmin3 is no more error.. and the table i create by 9.5 can be use(insert data) in pgAdmin3

Answer (score 0):

I am using the pgadmin version 4.6 which is the current release as for now.

I could only solve the problem by running query inside

```
    DO $$ ... BEGIN ... END $$;
```

block.

In case anyone still looking for an answer like me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when running a long series of queries in a transaction. Then when I ran them separately, it didn't loose the connection. Still no idea why it actually happens...

Answer (score 0):

My operating system is windows 10.
pgAdmin Version - 4.5

I was getting this error when executing scripts, downgrading to pgAdmin version 4.3 fixed the issue for me.