# Bug in pgadmin 4.3 for tables with json columns?

Tags: pgadmin-4

This looks a bit like this case here:
[PGAdmin: Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266659/pgadmin-not-connected-to-the-server-or-the-connection-to-the-server-has-been-cl)

Output of columns of type json seems not to work.

```
SELECT normal_column FROM table
```

Runs fine

```
SELECT * FROM table (or SELECT json_column FROM table)
```

> Outputs: "Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed."

But the notification window flashes the correct "Successfully run. N rows affected".

Did not have this problem with pgadmin 4.2 or 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed

please try to test with nightly build tomorrow Ref: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgadmin4.git;a=commitdiff;h=fbc6aea497c81b314e5744a24c643f369538a53d

Download: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/snapshots/

Comment: Try sending this issue to pgadmin-support email group.

Comment: @PEMegaard This is fixed now, please see updated answer